# To merge excels files by Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have many excel files(.xls) in one folder. Each excel contains strings and numbers. They don't have the same number of rows. How to read them and horizontally concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dir` function to get a list of files in the directory and the `xlsread` function to read in the contents of each file.

[link for dir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html)

[link for xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)

If you make an attempt and get stuck, you can get more help by asking a more specific question

Comment: Does xlsread can read contents that mixed with strings and numbers

Comment: yes, if you read the documentation that I linked to, you can see how.

Comment: I get the error, XLS File contains unicode text which is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks. There are too many files to convert into Excel 95 spreadsheet. And the strings (UTF8) become unreadable code after saving as excel 95.